# Postfix Expression - Checking for Spaces

Tags: c, stack, postfix-mta

So I am trying to add an `if` statement in my `main` function to check if there is some whitespace. If so it would just go on to the next number/operator in line. So for example, if I would type `2 3 4 * +`, I should get `14`. However, when I run the code I would get a random number. When I do it with no spaces such as `234*+`, then I would get 14. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I would fix this?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 20

typedef struct stack {
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
} stack;

int evaluate(char x, int op1, int op2) {
    if (x == '+')
        return (op1 + op2);
    if (x == '-')
        return (op1 - op2);
    if (x == '*')
        return (op1 * op2);
    if (x == '/')
        return (op1 / op2);
    if (x == '%')
        return (op1 % op2);
}

void init(stack *s) {
    s->top = -1;
}

void push(stack *s, int x) {
    s->top = s->top + 1;
    s->data[s->top] = x;
}

int pop(stack *s) {
    int x;
    x = s->data[s->top];
    s->top = s->top - 1;

    return (x);
}

int main() {
    stack s;
    char x;
    int op1, op2, val;
    init(&s);
    printf("Enter a Postfix Expression: ");

    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (isdigit(x))
            push(&s, x - 48); //x-48 for removing the effect of ASCII
        if (isspace(x))
            continue;
        else {
            op2 = pop(&s);
            op1 = pop(&s);
            val = evaluate(x, op1, op2);
            push(&s, val);
        }
    }

    val = pop(&s);
    printf("\nValue of expression=%d",val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the compiler errors and warnings and fix them first.

Comment: I had no errors. My code works but when I type in a Postfix Evaluation with white spaces, it gives me a random number.

Comment: My gcc compiler is telling me something different. For example you should declare and write the functions before you use them. This means, that your main function should be at the bottom of your text file. `test14.c:40:5: error: conflicting types for ‘evaluate’`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `char x` needs to be replaced with `int x`. The value returned by `getchar` won't always fit in a `char`. But that's not the problem you asked about.

---

If the character is a digit, you treat it as a digit and a operator. This

```c
    if(isdigit(x))
        push(&s,x-48); //x-48 for removing the effect of ASCII
    if (isspace(x))
        continue;
    else
    {
        op2=pop(&s);
        op1=pop(&s);
        val=evaluate(x,op1,op2);
        push(&s,val);
    }
```

should be

```c
    if (isdigit(x)) {
        push(&s, x-48);
    }
    else if (isspace(x)) {
       continue;
    }
    else {
        int op2 = pop(&s);
        int op1 = pop(&s);
        int val = evaluate(x, op1, op2);
        push(&s, val);
    }
```

or just

```c
    if (isdigit(x)) {
        push(&s, x-48);
    }
    else if (!isspace(x)) {
        int op2 = pop(&s);
        int op1 = pop(&s);
        int val = evaluate(x, op1, op2);
        push(&s, val);
    }
```

---

You shouldn't count on a trailing line feed. So you should really have the following:

```c
while ( ( x = getchar() ) != EOF ) {
    if (isspace(x))
        continue;

    if (isdigit(x)) {
        push(&s, x-48);
    } else {
        int op2 = pop(&s);
        int op1 = pop(&s);
        int val = evaluate(x, op1, op2);
        push(&s, val);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, you should handle someone entering `23++`, `234+` or `23!`.

Comment: I still seem to be getting an error when I’m typing spaces. Without spaces works totally fine. Do I need to change something with the if(isspace(x)) condition?

Comment: Well, the first solution didn't even compile cause it was missing a `{`. Once you add that, it works fine with both with and without spaces. The even better solution at the bottom worked as-is both with an without spaces. I don't know what you ran, but it wasn't my code

Comment: @AnthonySurface  I checked in my system. It worked for me too.

Comment: @ikegami  Please look at variable `x` inside main. It has benn declared as `char`.  It should be `int`  , since prototype of `getchar` is  `int getchar(void);` .  To accommodate EOF , the variable must be `int x` not   `char x`.  Please see this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/

Comment: @ikegami  Another link to support my comment ---> https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html

Comment: @ikegami   "If the integer value returned by `getchar()` is stored into a variable of type `char` and then compared against the integer constant EOF, the comparison may never succeed" .  I took this quote from second link mentioned above.

Comment: @Krishna Kanth Yenumula, Yes, it most definitely should be an `int`. Not sure why you're telling *me* that. It's a problem with the OP's code, not mine. That said, I've added a mention in my answer.